# Hyperledger composer network install

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Hi I'm having problem when trying to composer network install

Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: `Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed`

**composer network install**

[image: composer network install]

Comment: Is your Fabric started OK? `docker ps`  
There have been some recent releases of composer - are you using a compatible version of Composer and the underlying Fabric?  https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure docker is running

From their documentation,  [Installing pre-requisites](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html)

Docker is required.

Then try `docker ps`, check if the peer node/s is listed.

Then try to ping your network with `composer network ping --card admin@<some_network>`

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if docker login is working.
   If not,

   ```
   docker-machine ssh default
   sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
   ```

   change nameserver to 8.8.8.8
2. Using composer-cli at v0.19.5 
   Add this in fabric-scripts\hlfv11\createPeerAdminCard.sh

   ```
   CYGDIR="$(cygpath -pw "$DIR")"
   if [[ ! -v DOCKER_HOST ]]; then
   echo "DOCKER_HOST is NOT set <<<< Please set the env for Docker !!!!"
   DOCKER_IP="localhost"
   else
   DOCKER_IP="${DOCKER_HOST:6}"
   INDEX=`expr index "${DOCKER_IP}" :`
   echo $INDEX
   DOCKER_IP="${DOCKER_IP:0:(INDEX-1)}"
   fi
   echo  "Using the Docker VM IP Address: ${DOCKER_IP}"
   ```

   And replaced every localhost in the file with $DOCKER_IP