# BNA Creation in Fabric error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am in the process of deploying my .BNA file to fabric, I been testing and prototyping it in on the bluemix playground succesfully however, when I try to install the network application to fabric I get the error.

```
> Error: Error trying install business network. 

>Error: No valid responses from any peers.
>Response from attempted peer comms was an error: 
>Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
Command failed

**This is the steps I took** 

 1. Launch your Fabric network
> ./startFabric.sh

2.) Create the peer admin card

> ./createPeerAdminCard.sh

3.) Install the network application to fabric

> composer network install -a dist/bna.bna -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1

**This step is where I get the error**



      ✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
    Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
    Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
    Command failed
**Details of my env**

    Node Version: v8.11.3
    Docker version: 18.03
    Composer version: v0.19.12

Docker PS:
[Docker PS Screen shot][1]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQGBf.png


Any help is really appreciated.
```

**UPDATE**
*Connection.json for hlfv1*

```
    {
  "name": "hlfv1",
  "x-type": "hlfv1",
  "x-commitTimeout": 300,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "client": {
    "organization": "Org1",
    "connection": {
      "timeout": {
        "peer": {
          "endorser": "300",
          "eventHub": "300",
          "eventReg": "300"
        },
        "orderer": "300"
      }
    }
  },
  "channels": {
    "composerchannel": {
      "orderers": [
        "orderer.example.com"
      ],
      "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "organizations": {
    "Org1": {
      "mspid": "Org1MSP",
      "peers": [
        "peer0.org1.example.com"
      ],
      "certificateAuthorities": [
        "ca.org1.example.com"
      ]
    }
  },
  "orderers": {
    "orderer.example.com": {
      "url": "grpc://localhost:7050"
    }
  },
  "peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
      "url": "grpc://localhost:7051",
      "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:7053"
    }
  },
  "certificateAuthorities": {
    "ca.org1.example.com": {
      "url": "http://localhost:7054",
      "caName": "ca.org1.example.com"
    }
  }
}
```

**Hlfv11 vs HLFv1**
I noticed when I look in the the fabric-scrips there are two components hlfv11 vs hlfv1.

[Screen shot of fabric tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTUnE.png)

*When I start the startfabric I get the line that fabric assumes it is "hlfv11" instead of hlfv1*. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3YY3.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

```
docker inspect peer0.org1.example.com
[
    {
        "Id": "6caa83b2a8a5ee976c9066d0bbd98475e5bff885736ec9931606c33f06ccd9ac",
        "Created": "2018-07-20T22:49:51.238208735Z",
        "Path": "peer",
        "Args": [
            "node",
            "start"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 7506,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2018-07-20T22:49:51.543106588Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:b023f9be07714e495e6d41849d7e916434e85580754423ece145866468ad29a9",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/6caa83b2a8a5ee976c9066d0bbd98475e5bff885736ec9931606c33f06ccd9ac/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/6caa83b2a8a5ee976c9066d0bbd98475e5bff885736ec9931606c33f06ccd9ac/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/6caa83b2a8a5ee976c9066d0bbd98475e5bff885736ec9931606c33f06ccd9ac/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/6caa83b2a8a5ee976c9066d0bbd98475e5bff885736ec9931606c33f06ccd9ac/6caa83b2a8a5ee976c9066d0bbd98475e5bff885736ec9931606c33f06ccd9ac-json.log",
        "Name": "/peer0.org1.example.com",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/var/run:/host/var/run:rw",
                "/Users/wppa/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users:rw",
                "/Users/wppa/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer:/etc/hyperledger/configtx:rw",
                "/Users/wppa/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "composer_default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "7051/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "7051"
                    }
                ],
                "7053/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "7053"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": null,
            "Name": "aufs"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/var/run",
                "Destination": "/host/var/run",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/wppa/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users",
                "Destination": "/etc/hyperledger/msp/users",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/wppa/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer",
                "Destination": "/etc/hyperledger/configtx",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/wppa/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp",
                "Destination": "/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "6caa83b2a8a5",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "7051/tcp": {},
                "7053/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug",
                "CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG",
                "CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock",
                "CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com",
                "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051",
                "CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=composer_default",
                "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP",
                "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp",
                "CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB",
                "CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "peer",
                "node",
                "start"
            ],
            "Image": "hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0",
            "Volumes": {
                "/etc/hyperledger/configtx": {},
                "/etc/hyperledger/msp/users": {},
                "/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp": {},
                "/host/var/run": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "d44983248579bb25822020f82382fba01b891c3338b2fe91bb17ac3936126c69",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "composer",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "peer0.org1.example.com",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.21.1",
                "org.hyperledger.fabric.base.version": "0.4.6",
                "org.hyperledger.fabric.version": "1.1.0"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "5645c1988100b53fa9a8c2d13adc40c43f3995cb808b3eda28771176033b26b4",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "7051/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "7051"
                    }
                ],
                "7053/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "7053"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/5645c1988100",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "composer_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "peer0.org1.example.com",
                        "6caa83b2a8a5"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "d4f496b7b3aeae87d1b1461523bc8620ac34b54d9b3b9f8d31c6cfa7be4da024",
                    "EndpointID": "a19687702d04e166dc0291dc9ce1130caf5eccf484ece4fd988c13cc2660c8fb",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.5",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:05",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Fixed: Needed to reinstall Hyperledger fabric, composer, node, npm, and docker. And need to set "unset ${!DOCKER*}" there seemed to an docker issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually seen when the CLI cannot connect to the Fabric using the addresses specified in the PeerAdmin's connection.json file. Did you download the latest fabric-tools as shown [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html) prior to this?

Sometimes if there is a proxy involved (on a corporate network), there can be some routing failures.

see answer here which may help you -> [Hyperledger composer network install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625575/hyperledger-composer-network-install)

Comment: Hi Paul, I checked the fabric tools and it seems to be the same methodology I followed. I updated my question with connection.json and other things

Comment: You wrote "when I try to install the network application (bna) to fabric I get the error" -  I am assuming everything is local - on your laptop? That is the intended environment (a local dev environment - as you can see the connection profile is set up to use exactly that). You can ignore hlfv1 vs hlfv11 in connection profile. Someone has suggested to try `0.0.0.0` in the connection.json of the PeerAdmin currently under $HOME/.composer (the createPeerAdminCard script file creates a connection.json file  with 'localhost' set) as shown [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3002)

Comment: hey I am running this locally. I still cant get it to work and am getting the same error. I completely uninstalled composer using hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/…, and reinstalled composer development environment using hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/installing/… and I used this to do some quick testing and I getting the same error?hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/…. I also changed the connection.json file  any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

ERROR 14 means that you the composer can't locate the peers. Your issue is here:

```
  "peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
  }
```

you need to write something like:

```
"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://localhost:7051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:7053"
    }
}
```

FIXED: 
I uninstalled docker, node, npm, and reinstalled everthing and made sure to use unset ${!DOCKER*} when first installing docker for Mac OS

Comment: If your peers are running on localhost and those ports then that should be the correct url and event url. do `docker inspect` on your peer container and it will tell you the correct ports.

Comment: hey I am running this locally. I still cant get it to work and am getting the same error. I completely uninstalled composer using https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/uninstall-dev-env, and reinstalled composer development environment using https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/installing/development-tools.html and I used this to do some quick testing and I getting the same error?https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial. I also changed the connection.json file

Comment: what does `docker inspect peer0.org1.example.com` output say regarding ports the peer is connected to?