# Hyperledger composer network install continuing

Tags: docker, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

LS,
currently I am doing an online Hyperledger development couse: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html.

In step 4 of this course I have to deploy a business network which starts with the execution of the command:

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna
```

As result of this command I get the following error message:

```
kees@kees-VirtualBox:~/tutorial-network$ composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna
✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
```

Response from attempted peer comms was an error:

```
Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
Command failed
```

In the stackoverview post titled “Hyperledger composer network install” ([Hyperledger composer network install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625575/hyperledger-composer-network-install)) my problem, which I currently experience, is described. 
However the solutions mentioned in this post are not clear to me.

So I have many questions as result of solution information:

Am I running a wrong version of the composer software? Hoe can I see which version I am currently running? And how do I change it to an other version?

When I execute `docker ps`, I see only the column names of the report, no contents, no peers.

The command `composer network ping --card admin@<some_network>` gives an error message.

By the way the documentation doesn’t give instructions about any initialization of the Docker-system.

The command `docker-machine ssh default sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf` is only partly recognized, so could not be executed.

I have created a Docker-Id and I have been able to login. But that solved not my problems.  No idea how to change the name server to `8.8.8.8`.  I have also added the code in `fabric-cripts\hlfv11\createPeerAdminCard.sh`:

```
CYGDIR="$(cygpath -pw "$DIR")"
if [[ ! -v DOCKER_HOST ]]; then
    echo "DOCKER_HOST is NOT set 
    <<<< Please set the env for Docker !!!!"
    DOCKER_IP="localhost"
else
    DOCKER_IP="${DOCKER_HOST:6}"
    INDEX=`expr index "${DOCKER_IP}" :`
    echo $INDEX
    DOCKER_IP="${DOCKER_IP:0:(INDEX-1)}"
fi
echo  "Using the Docker VM IP Address:
${DOCKER_IP}"
```

Also this code didn’t solve my problem.  Can you clarify what I should do to solve my problem?  This problem prevents me from attending further the development course.

With kind regards,
Kees Besse

Comment: Kees, you need to set up a running Fabric - your docker ps confirms you haven't done so. Also - did you follow the prerequisites https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html and are certain that you have the right versions of essential software, such as the Docker version? The documentation (and the tutorial) does say to start a 'development Fabric' , specifically steps Three and Four here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

Comment: Once you've done the Development setup - you can do the tutorial quickly and easily. You shouldn't need to worry about docker resolution issues (the tutorial doesn't say to use docker-machine).  You can use `composer -v` to get the Composer version FYI.

Comment: Paul, thanks very much for reviewing my problem. I have carried out all steps which needed to be done previously. I checked the start of ‘development Fabric’, step Three and Four. In step Three VSCode Is installed, I have downloaded it again and executed it.  In step Four library Fabric-dev-servers is created and this folder was indeed available in my Ubuntu. My composer version is V0.19.12 . Let me know if you have other suggestions which I could check. Kees

Comment: On this problem I received an email from a Hyperledger developer (via an IBM courseware developer) with a suggestion which should solve my problem:
“It looks like the Business Network (chaincode) has been installed, so it should be ok to use this command to continue:
composer network start specifying carauction-network as the network name and 0.2.6-20180530153450 as the version.”
Based of this feedback I created the following command:
composer network start --networkName carauction-network --networkVersion 0.2.6-20180530153450 --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 

Continued in next comment.

Comment: When I executie this command, I get the message that the argument “networkAdmin” is missing.

Furthermore I assume that more operators of this command are missing, when I look at the command description from the manual:

composer network start --networkName <business-network-name> --networkVersion <business-network-version> --networkAdmin <admin-name> --networkAdminEnrollSecret <enroll-secret> --card <peer-admin-card> --file <admin-card-file-name>

Please let me know if somebody has suggestions how my problem needs to be solved.

Comment: `composer network start --networkName carauction-network --networkVersion 0.2.6-20180530153450 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card` then do `composer card import -f networkadmin.card` then do `composer network ping -c admin@carauction-network` and see if you can ping the network (assuming you haven't restarted your Fabric environment since you first tried the network install etc etc). If successful you can `rm networkadmin.card` (no longer needed)

Comment: I have executed the first ¨composer network start¨-command. And this resulted in an error:
kees@kees-VirtualBox:~$ composer network start --networkName carauction-network --networkVersion 0.2.6-20180530153450 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
Starting business network carauction-network at version 0.2.6-20180530153450

Comment: Processing these Network Admins:
userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Unable to initalize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
Command failed

Comment: hi Kees, I'm not convinced you've started a Fabric network: can you paste the output of `docker ps` please? You need to have started the Development-based Fabric environment from `fabric-tools` using `./startFabric.sh`

Comment: This is the output of the docker ps command. To me it looks empty:kees@kees-VirtualBox:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

Comment: I do not have a fabric-tool library: kees@kees-VirtualBox:~$ cd ~/fabric-tools
bash: cd: /home/kees/fabric-tools: No such file or directory

Comment: When I just start the command ./startFabric.sh - , it results in some errors, the last lines are pasted
in this post:
ERROR: for orderer.example.com  Cannot start service orderer.example.com: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint orderer.example.com (64516dc202e9a5b490f4b2f75cb80b847d2464adf9c48b0c28faf39ca6f7ab6d): Bind for 0.0.0.0:7050 failed: port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: OK - `fabric-tools` is just a 'tools' directory name eg equivalent is really `fabric-dev-servers` (although you also wrote that you had a`fabric-cripts` directory btw) anyway, whatever the name of the dir is for the tools directory.  The problem is you started changing scripts (you wrote of above) so not sure what's affected - so   I would 1) `rm -rf fabric-dev-servers` directory (and similar other tools directory names you created  2) `mkdir fabric-dev-servers` && `cd fabric-dev-servers` - making sure you've successfully entered that directory - then and only then do

Comment: (continued)....3) go and run the curl command to download a new fabric-dev-servers zip image - ie what it says in Step Four here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html 4) `docker ps -qa | xargs docker rm` to clear your containers 5) `rm -rf $HOME/.composer` 6) `./startFabric.sh` - if successful then do 7) `./createPeerAdminCard.sh`

Comment: The advice in this forum helped me to solve my problem. But when this was solved a new problem raised in the next command which I have to execute according to the guide.
Due to private reasons I have to stop temporary with this course. I hope to continue in the near future.